# Print the number of line in a python difflib file

Tags: python, diff, difflib

I am trying to find the difference between 2 text files using difflib in Python. I am able to print text which have been added or removed in the new file. But I want to print in which line the modification has been made. Even though I know how to count the number of lines in the file, I am unable to print the lines which have been added or removed. My code is here :

```
import difflib
import time


def get_diff(old_file, new_file):
    f1 = open(old_file, 'r')
    f2 = open(new_file, 'r')

    old_file = f1.readlines()
    new_file = f2.readlines()

    diff = difflib.unified_diff(old_file, new_file, lineterm='')
    lines = list(diff)[2:]
    added = [lineA for lineA in lines if lineA[0] == '+']


    with open("output.txt", "w") as fh1:
     for line in added:
       fh1.write(line)
    print '+',added
    removed = [lineB for lineB in lines if lineB[0] == '-']
    with open("output.txt", "a") as fh1:
     for line in removed:
       fh1.write(line)
    print '-',removed


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fh = get_diff("ex.txt","ex2.txt")
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The [unified diff](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.unified_diff) already contains information about the differing lines:

```
--- before.py
+++ after.py
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-bacon
-eggs
-ham
+python
+eggy
+hamster
 guido
```

The third line `@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@` tells you the location of the change.

Comment: Hom Can you please explain it? I did not understand how to read those numbers